# jQuery plugin is working with old version not with new version

Tags: jquery

I was used this plugin for news tickr. Link: http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/

This plugin is working great with jQuery 1.6. But, not working with latest jQuery. How can I make this working with Latest jQuery?

You can find the plugin documentation on that site. Anyone can help?

Comment: I think this question is for the product owner of your plugin.

Comment: jQuery 2.0 has dropped support for older versions of IE. Try using the latest 1.10.x version of jQuery instead, which should be functionally identical but retains support for IE weirdness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems like it is using `live` which is deprecated and removed in the newer versions. But you can use [jquery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) for backward compatibility or for a quick fix just try adding this:

```
$.fn.live = $.fn.on;
```

Before calling the plugin function. Though this wont have support for dynamic elements as `live` does due to the syntax change in event delegation in `on`. But this will get going for static content.

Here is a fiddle that works with 2.x version of jquery.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8jhJU/)**

Comment: @RaselAhmed see if you can switch over to another plugin, because it seems like that plug in is old and is no longer under development.....

Comment: I can't find a plugin like that. Do you have similar updated plugin? Thanks again for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going from jQuery 1.6 to jQuery 2.x...that's a huge jump. Ensure that the plug-in even offers support for 2.x. If not, you can either use jQuery 1.x latest (which still has all the features of 2.x for now), or, use [jQuery migrat](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)e to help transition between the versions. (jQuery migrate provides support for backwards compatibility.)